# MongoDB - Calculate field based on previous item

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a tricky scenario - I need to calculate extra field, based on value from previous field. I have no idea how to do it in performant manner. Any thoughts?

**Data:**

```js
{
    _id: 1,
    score: 66,
    created_at: "2021-04-01"
},
{
    _id: 2,
    score: 12,
    created_at: "2021-04-03"
},
{
    _id: 3,
    score: 7,
    created_at: "2021-04-06"
}
```

**What I want to achieve**

```js
{
    _id: 1,
    score: 66,
    total_score: 66  // The most oldest item, so total score is the same as current score
    created_at: "2021-04-01"
},
{
    _id: 2,
    score: 12,
    total_score: 78  // Sum of current score and previous total_score
    created_at: "2021-04-03"
},
{
    _id: 3,
    score: 7,
    total_score: 85  // Sum of current score and previous total_score
    created_at: "2021-04-06"
}
```

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: In Mongo 5.0 you could use [$setWindowFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/) - however, if you need only the previous item, then it might be an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aggregation query,

- `$lookup` with pipeline and match greater than query by `_id` to select the previous record
- `$group` by null and get the sum of `score`
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from lookup result
- `$ifNull` to check if the result is null then return 0 otherwise return the current value
- `$add` to get total of `score` and return score from lookup

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: { id: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $gt: ["$$id", "$_id"] } } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            score: { $sum: "$score" }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "total_score"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      total_score: {
        $add: [
          "$score",
          {
            $ifNull: [
              { $arrayElemAt: ["$total_score.score", 0] },
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xWL-JV2gT3i)